# Cloning git repository failed using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket, egit, git-clone

Trying to pull the fresh code from bitbucket and I am continuously getting read time out error.

[image]

A popup comes that just says:

```
Git repository clone failed.
Read timed out.
```

Clicking on *Show Error Log* says-

> Plug-in: org.eclipse.egit.ui
>
> Date: current time of failure

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the way figured out correctly,

*Going to*- `Window -> Preferences -> Team -> Git`

And set *`Remote Connection timeout(seconds)`* to some higher value.

The default is set to 30 seconds.

When set to 180 seconds and tried to pull, it worked.

Comment: it saved me too... @my-god

Answer (score 0):

Egit wasn't able to read the remote repository. It got a timeout.

Make sure that you have proper access to the repo. Check your network connectivity, check ssh keys and/or passwords, check permissions. Does it work on another pc?